# How do i cat two files as arguments to a command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm doing a little bulkrenaming bash script.

It goes like this:

```
for file in ./*; do
    filename="$(basename "$file")"
    echo $filename >> .bulkren1
    echo $filename >> .bulkren2
done

$EDITOR .bulkren2
```

Now i have two files:

.bulkren1 with the old names

.bulkren2 with the new names

I want to get each line and do a mv -i -- "$oldname" "$newname" with double quotes so i can use spaces and other characters. What's the best way to do this?

I'm trying in a lot of ways with no success.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use only one file?

Comment: BTW, `echo "$filename"` is going to be less mishap-prone than `echo $filename`; [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) applies. (Even better than that would be `printf '%s\n' "$filename"`, which correctly handles some filenames `echo` can choke on).

Comment: With one file only how would i encapsulate both names within double quotes?
Should i add double quotes in file1 and file2 and paste -d file1 file2 > file3 ?

Comment: That's a good question! How about you ask it as a separate question? It deserves its own post.

Comment: @Grand0rbiter, I assume that mkrieger1 suggests iterating over `./*` and the contents of `.bulkren2` in lockstep. Requires being able to assume that the directory's contents haven't changed, ofc, so it's a bit risky. Not sure what you're talking about re: quotes -- you should never have quotes **in** the files; that would make them data, they only have meaning/use when they're syntax.

Comment: `items=( ./* ) && printf '%s\n' "${items[@]}" >file && "$EDITOR" file && readarray -t newItems <file`, and now you have an array of original names in `"${items[@]}"` and an array of new names in `"${newItems[@]}"`. `for idx in "${!items[@]}"; do mv -i -- "${items[$idx]}" "${newItems[$idx]}"; done`, or such.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so maybe this is a task that's beyond my knowledge.

I was doing mostly as an exercise in learning bash. It's my first time trying to learn programming.

Comment: Well, you're coming away from this with plenty of places to start from in your research, so that's not a bad thing. BTW, I strongly suggest the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) -- see #1 and #5 as relevant to your immediate question, and whereas #50 isn't *directly* on-point, if you get to a point where you understand its reasoning, you'll know bash's quoting rules well enough to be in a good place with them.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Plenty of info there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, I meant putting pairs of (old name, new name) per line in one file, then iterating over this file and for each pair do the rename. The whole “how to read from two files in parallel” and “how to put quotes” seems like an XY problem, the actual problem seems to be “how to bulk rename files”.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ahh. Of course, whatever character you use as a column separator can no longer be allowed in the names, unless *both* versions get `printf %q`-style quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from two files in parallel is tricky. You need to open both files with unique file descriptors (here, 3 and 4) and then read from them line by line with two `read` statements in a loop.

```
exec 3< .bulkren1
exec 4< .bulkren2

while IFS= read -r oldname <&3 && IFS= read -r newname <&4; do
    mv -i -- "$oldname" "$newname"
done

exec 3<&- 4<&-    # Close files.
```

You could condense it down by combining the `exec`s with the loop. It gets rid of the need to close the files at the end, but readability suffers:

```
while IFS= read -r oldname <&3 && IFS= read -r newname <&4; do
    mv -i -- "$oldname" "$newname"
done 3<.bulkren1 4<.bulkren2
```